# How to create Jetpack compose hello world

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

[image]I have checked many examples on the internet and tried them and I get persistent error messages. The code setContent cannot be detected even if I try adding library in the gradle. The following are, in my opinion, the simplest examples I can find yet I get errors. Can someone help?

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup
https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/general/helloworld/

Comment: What errors? Share more details. Creating a new Android Studio project with Compose template will give the expected result.

Comment: IIRC the minimum Android Studio version that suppor JetpackCompose is Artic Fox, did yours already met the requirement? I'm only guessing the problem here, please provide the complete error log so others can help you easily.

Comment: I'm using android studio dolphin. I have to edit the question to insert the error message. Please refer to it. Please take note that I have already sent this problem to the android development team.